# Best way to model data in nested arrays across local and remote schemas in Apollo GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-tools

I am new to graphql and apollo. I've got a local Graphql schema which is using nested arrays of objects and is mapped over to mongoDB in the resolvers with Mongoose.

```
type Category {
    id: ID!
    category: String!
    sections: [Section]
}

type SurveyType {
    id: ID!
    stype(type: SurveyTypeChoice): String
    categories: [Category] 
}
```

My queries to this work fine, but I also have a remote schema which is from a hasura instance I have running and maps on to a postgreSQL DB. This remote schema contains question information. I have merged these schemas using the graphql-tools module and can now query both schemas independently through my local apollo server instance.

My problem is that for the Section type in the schema above, i would like it to be in this format:

```
type Section {
    id: ID!
    section: String!
    leadText: String!
    questions: [Question] // Question here is an object from the remote schema
}
```

Is there a way to implement this kind of model and modify the resolvers such that I could query down to the Section level and obtain the array of questions from the remote schema?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree? If so can anyone think of a better way to model this kind of data across schemas?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a newbie with GraphQL. I personally have not used Hasura, but I recently found [this](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/2494) issue and I think it can help you solve your issue. It is really declarative and contains lots of details on how to implement a sample solution.

I hope that helps! Please let me know if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks George, very useful! Remote joins seem to be the key

Comment: Nice to hear that. If it helped you can you accept or upvote my answer?

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it!